# Post titles separated by comma in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, arrays, wordpress

I know that i can separate post titles with a comma, when I have a loop:

```
<?php           
$medium_posts = new WP_Query ($medium_query);
?>

<span class="archive-list"> 
<?php while ( $medium_posts->have_posts() ) : $medium_posts->the_post(); ?>
<?php echo (($medium_posts->current_post!=0)?'<span class="separator">,</span> ':''); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile ?>
</span>
```

But what if I have a situation, where i have a mysql query, and like to separate the post titles by comma?

```
        <?php
    $posts = $wpdb->get_col("
                SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
                FROM $wpdb->posts
                WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
                AND post_type = 'works' 
                AND MONTH(post_date) = '".$month."' 
                AND YEAR(post_date) = '".$year."' 
                ORDER BY post_date DESC");

        $the_posts = array();
        foreach($posts as $post) :
    ?>

<span class="archive-list">
<?php
$the_posts[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post ) . '">' . get_the_title( $post ) . '</a>';
echo implode( ', ', $the_posts ); ?>
</span> 

    <?php endforeach;?>
```

With this code it starts to dublicate the first post in the output like this:

> My first title My first title,  My second title My first title, My
>   second title My third title My first title,

…

How to get the titles separated by comma?
Like this: Title 1, Title 2, Title 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

`echo implode( ', ', $the_posts );`

after `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

First store all the title in an array and use implode

```
$titles = array();

// logic to save all titles into this array

$comma_seperated = implode(', ', $titles);
```

and possibly you can try array_unique before implode, if that can solve your issue.

```
$titles = array_unique($titles);
```